# Select element after .wrap()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Helo I use this code:

```
cur = $('input:radio');
cur.wrap('<span class="customRadio"></span>');
```

what i must to do to acces the '.customRadio' element?
I already tried:

```
cur.parent('.customRadio')
```

and

```
$('.customRadio')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/QD35Z/

```
<div id="mah">hello</div>

var $parent = $('#mah').wrap('<span id="test"></span>').parent();
alert($parent.attr("id"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wrapper = $('<span class="customRadio"></span>')
```

Then wrapper is a span element and you can use it in jQuery:

```
cur.wrap(wrapper)
```

<strike>And you have access to the wrapper:</strike>

**EDIT**: Sorry, you can only access the wrapper before you wrap it around your target element. The actual element wrapped around the target is not the one you have access to.

```
// Effects the span that will be wrapped:
wrapper.css('color', 'red')
cur.wrap(wrapper)
// Doesn't effect the span that was wrapped:
wrapper.css('border', '1px solid green')
```

Answer (score 0):

And by using `closest`?

```
var custom = cur.closest(".customRadio");
```